# Javascript - Issue with Arrow Function

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner with Javascript and my teacher gave me this code :

```
var z = (x=>(y=>2*y)(x)+3)(5);
```

(Sorry for my English, I'm a French guy with a bad level of English ^^)

I have to re-write this code with simple functions but I'm not sure of myself.

For me, I can re-write this code like :

```
var x = 5;
var y = 2 * x;
var z = y + 3;
```

But, it's not re-write with simples functions.

My question is : can you help me to understand how arrow function works in this case and give me an idea how to re-write this code with simple functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Arrow functions that have `a => b` form implicitly return `b` when called. You can imagine them like:

```
function (a) { return b }
```

Additionally, your code sample is wrapped in `()` and immediately invoked, pattern known as the [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
(a => b)(3)
```

which is the same as

```
(function (a) { return b })(3)
```

Where both functions get defined and invoked immediately, hence the name.

Now all you have to do is use these two ideas, implicit returns and IIFEs for arrow functions, to re-write your example as plain functions with explicit returns and regular IIFEs.

In other words:

1. Add `return` statements where they are assumed to exist (implicit in arrow functions)
2. Add `function()` around each arrow function's arguments.

---

Here's what is happening in your code sample in plain English:

- Pass `5` into an IIFE which takes `x`
- Pass that `x` down to another IIFE which takes `y`
- Return `2 * y` from the second IIFE
- Add `3` to what was return from second IIFE
- Return result from the first IIFE

Or as a math formula:

```
z = x = (2 * y) + 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will learn more about the inner IIFE but I have understood my exercise with your answer.

Comment: No problem mate, glad to help

Answer (score -1):

We have:

```
var z = (x=>(y=>2*y)(x)+3)(5);
```

The arrow function definition says that `x=>(....)` means `(function(x){ return ...})`

So

```
var z = (function(x) {
    return (y=>2*y)(x)+3;
})(5);
```

We have now another arrow function `y=>2*y`, that means `(function(y) { return 2*y})`.

So

```
var z = (function(x) {
    return (function(y) {
            return 2*y;
        })(x) + 3;
})(5);
```

And that's all.

Remember that `(function(){})()` it's an anonymous function declaration executed immediately. So at the end, the var `z` is a simple number.